# Is there a time limit for voting to reopen questions?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

To cast a reopen vote requires 500 rep (17 users at the moment). If a user reaches 500 many days after the question has be closed, can they still vote to reopen, or must this be done soon after the closing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a time limit, but a closed post can't be deleted for 2 days. If after 2 days, a mod wants to delete the post, they can.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. I know "close" votes fade away if five aren't reached within a few days of each other.